# Get difference between two dates

Tags: ios, swift, time, nsdate

I need the difference between milliseconds and the date at the moment. It needs to be formatted as HH:mm:ss and my code is not coming out with the correct difference.

```
var differenceDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(currentTimeInMiliseconds()))
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        self.callDetail.text = dateFormatter.string(from: differenceDate as Date)

 func currentTimeInMiliseconds() -> Int! {
        let date = NSDate()
        return Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
```

Comment: A date is a number of seconds under the hood. But a count of seconds (milliseconds) is not a date! Your use of DateFormatter is completely inappropriate here.

Comment: My business rules require me to use milliseconds so I have to use it. Double(currentTimeInMiliseconds actually goes to a variable holding the milliseconds but I changed it to better explain.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the milliseconds. Listen to what I'm saying. `differenceDate` is not a date. It cannot be "formatted as HH:mm:ss" using a date formatter. It isn't a date. Not. A. Date.

Comment: What two dates are you referring to? One seems to be "now". But what is the other date? The code you posted in your question doesn't make use of a second date anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the amount of time between two date objects in a `HH:mm:ss` format, you generally would use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`. In Swift 3:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad

let string = formatter.string(from: referenceDate, to: date)
```

In Swift 2:

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Positional
formatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour, .Minute, .Second]
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad

let string = formatter.stringFromDate(referenceDate, toDate: date)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `differenceDate`, despite the name, is not a date! It's just a time interval — an abstract number of seconds. If you want to express it as hours and minutes and seconds, just keep dividing by 60 and taking the remainder. But bear in mind that those are not *real* hours and minutes and seconds.

Example:

```
// make two dates, get the difference
let greg = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let dc = DateComponents(calendar: greg, 
    year: 1954, month: 8, day: 10, hour: 3, minute: 0, second: 0)
let d1 = greg.date(from: dc)!
let d2 = Date()
let diff = d2.timeIntervalSince(d1)

// calculate hours, minutes, and seconds
var min = diff/60
let sec = diff.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)
let hr = min/60
min = min.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)

// format the output as a string
let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.roundingMode = .floor
nf.minimumIntegerDigits = 2

let hrs = nf.string(from: hr as NSNumber)
let mins = nf.string(from: min as NSNumber)

nf.maximumFractionDigits = 3
let secs = nf.string(from: sec as NSNumber)

print(hrs! + ":" + mins! + ":" + secs!) // 545169:33:18.841
```

This gives you your desired formatting and your milliseconds. You can do the same thing with DateComponentsFormatter, as suggested by Rob, but you'll get exactly the same calculated result.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way was to use NSCalendar

```
let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.current as NSCalendar
        let date1 = call!.startTime.dateFromMilliseconds()
        let date2 = NSDate()
        let components = calendar.components([.hour, .second, .minute], from: date1 , to: date2 as Date, options: [])
        differenceDate =  NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)?.date(from: components) as NSDate!
```